# How to wrap content around a display suite region?

Tags: theming, location, display-suite

I'm using the nifty [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) module to create a custom layout for an event page. I'm using the stacked fluid 2 column layout with the Body field on the left and the image and event fields in the left column.

I would like the body (left region) to wrap around the image and date fields (right region). I''ve been unable to figure out to to accomplish this.

http://ctu.robohobo.net/node/17

How  would I make that happen?

Drupal: 7.19
Display Suite: 7.x-2.0

Comment: it was hard to understand what you want, can you provide a picture for your desired look ?

Comment: This is essentially a HTML + CSS question, is it? The Display Suite does not really matter.

Comment: You first say "a custom layout", then you say "I'm using the stacked fluid 2 column layout". So in fact you are using a predefined layout, not a custom one.

Comment: You want to look for [hook_ds_layout_info()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ds!ds.api.php/function/hook_ds_layout_info/7). The benefit of a custom layout is you can reuse it in other places. Your CSS can be targeted at the layout, instead of being targeted at a special case.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue you need to reorder your html by flipping columns in your custom layout

If you inspect your html you'll see that group-left renders first then group-right

```
<div class="group-left">content</div>

<section class="group-right">image and location </section>
```

So you need to have the following structure:

```
<div class="group-left">image and location </div>

<section class="group-right">content</section>
```

Then add the following style to your css file

```
.ds-2col-stacked > .group-left {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
}

.ds-2col-stacked > .group-right {
  float: none;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change structure of template file of display suite module file named ds-2col.tpl.php in :

**your project > sites > all > ds > layouts > ds_2col > ds-2col.tpl.php**